# How to center the ul in the HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this html and CSS code on which I have spent the last 3 hrs and I am still not able to figure out how to center align the top menu bar in my code. The code is as follows:

```css
#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#container ul li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container ul li {
  background-color: #6068FF;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18;
}

#container ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0BF5F5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="default.asp">Student Attendance</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="news.asp">Edit Students</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="contact.asp">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="about.asp">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Step 1: Stop using float. float and centering are diametrically opposed concepts to begin with.

Comment: few things: `background-color` can be shortened to `background`. `white` can be shortened to `#fff`. Don't use float, use `display: inline-block` to get things aligned. To center an element, you have to target the parent of the desired element to be centered. Also no inline css/js - its bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox for this:

```css
#container {
  display: flex; /* new */
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;  
}

#container ul li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container ul li {
  background-color: #6068FF;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18;
}

#container ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0BF5F5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="default.asp">Student Attendance</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="news.asp">Edit Students</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="contact.asp">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="about.asp">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your updated CSS:

Added `text-align: center` on the `<ul>` tag.

```
#container ul {
    ...
    text-align: center;
}
```

Removed `float: left`, and added `display: inline-block` on `<li>` tags.

```
#container ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   ...
   /* float: left; */
}
```

Comment: still aligned left

Comment: Please make an effort of reading my provided solution along with its tag description. If you'd like a copy-and-paste codes, then use the other answers as they've provided both *HTML* and *CSS*.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to display the list as an inline element or give it a fixed with, otherwise it always will take full available horizontal space.

```
#container ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0;             
}

/* or */

#container ul {
    width: 50%; /* whatever */
    list-style:none;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0;             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code without the `float:left;`

```css
   #container ul {
        list-style:none;
        margin:auto;
        padding: 0;             
    }

    #container ul li a{
        color:#FFFFFF;          
    }   
    #container ul li{
        background-color:#6068FF;
        width:180px;
        border:1px solid white;
        height:50px;
        line-height:50px;
        text-align:center;
        #float:left;
        align-items:center;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size:18;   
    }

    #container ul li:hover{
        background-color:#0BF5F5;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
  <li><a style="text-decoration:none;"href="default.asp">Student Attendance</a></li>
  <li><a style="text-decoration:none;"href="news.asp">Edit Students</a></li>
  <li><a style="text-decoration:none;"href="contact.asp">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a style="text-decoration:none;"href="about.asp">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to create a horizontal menu bar so if I remove the float ,the items are listed vertically.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think you want to center them so the items will be listed vertically.

Comment: no i want it to be horizontal but there is enough space on both sides so i wanted it to centered

Answer (score 0):

Add `inline-block` to the list and use `text-align:center;` on the `#container`

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container ul li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container ul li {
  background-color: #6068FF;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18;
}

#container ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0BF5F5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="default.asp">Student Attendance</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="news.asp">Edit Students</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="contact.asp">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="about.asp">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```